# my mac os x app is unresponsive even though im using nsoperations and set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 3

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

i have been looking at stack overflow for long time but never really got a chance to make my first question, so here it is:

i am developing a mac os x app and using nsoperations to keep the app responsive,
i also set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 3, however the app is still somewhat unresponsive while doing its work, if it ry to move the window around i can see it starts to lag and behave erratically

can someone provide any clue or pointer to solution ?
(no, not asking sample code ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons why an app might be unresponsive in such a situation:

- you are straight up blocking the main event loop or flooding it with events
- you have complex drawing operations on the main thread
- your app is using so much memory that it is causing the system to page.  Doesn't really matter if you have 10 threads or 1 thread, as soon as you start paging, your performance goes down the tubes
- you have lock contention between the main thread and the background thread(s)/queue(s)

Instruments offers a series of tools for profiling CPU usage.  The first thing I'd do is to figure it if the main thread is using a lot of CPU (and, if so, for what?) or if it is blocked waiting on locks or the like.

Comment: tx alot for your quick input bbum,

as i am not used used to stackoverflow i did not know i was not receiving notices when some answer arrived 

sorry for not providing enough input:
i am not really doing anything on main thread other than just ui stuff, ibactions and delegates,
all heavier stuff is done on background thru the NSOperationQueue

no drawing at all

my app almost does not use really much memory (around 50mb real on activity monitor) despite dealing with several 60mb-100mb files (wav files)
cpu is never over 10 % and usually around 6% while processing

i am using no locks

Comment: i just found out i am too novice to able to mark your answers as useful :(sorry)

Comment: hehehe, yes, i noticed that afterwards…
i guess i should have removed that post / question….
should i do it now ?

Answer (score 1):

If the app becomes unresponsive you are blocking the main thread somewhere in your code, take a sample using activity monitor or instruments ( recommended ) to find out where in your code.

Comment: the app does not really get completelly unresponsive,
i just notice that if i grab the window and move it around while it is processing it has not a smooth motion as other apps do while also doing heavier work, 

i also notice severe glitches in audio sound, i am using audiotoolbox framework but no clue why it should be related...

(whay a nightmare, everytime i press return for newline stackoverflow submits this commennt, grrrr, sorry guys, 1st posts… i will get the hang of it :)

Comment: by the way i did take a sample on activity monitor while the app was processing but i am not sure what to look for...

Comment: i just found out i am too novice to able to mark your answers as useful :(sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Just using NSOperations won't make the app responsive. The key to responsiveness is to not block the main thread. If your app is laggy, it's (usually—see @bbum's answer) because you're doing something or things that are blocking the main thread.

The way to find out what is to use Instruments. Use the Time Profiler instrument, and then look at what is running on the main thread. Make those things smaller, move them to operations, delayed-perform them, or some combination thereof. If you need to refactor, do it.

One possibility is that you are running your operations on [the main queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/mainQueue). Don't do that—they will run serially (regardless of `maxOperationCount`) on the main thread. Create a queue and use the queue you created.

Comment: hi peter, thanks for dropping in so fast

as i told in previous reply i did not know i already had 3 replies waiting for me, i just kept coding and now i remembered to check :)

as i mention before i am not doing anything intensive on main thread , just waiting for events to happen (mainly drag and drop files or using open panel to start processing, on nsoperation queue)

i am also not sure i was clear, the app does not et fully unreponsive, all ui responds perfectly, it just seems to have quirky behaviour while processing (previous replies have more info)

Comment: i just found out i am too novice to able to mark your answers as useful :(sorry)

Comment: @Nonnus: You should not do drag-and-drop or run an Open panel on an operation queue, except the main thread, because you should do those things only on the main thread. You should also not “wait for events to happen”; that is the run loop's job. If you have to wait for something, return and let the run loop tell you about it.

Comment: i am afraid maybe i was not clear enough: 
my drag and drop handling is on the main thread, 
it is almost the only thing going on there

what i mean by wait for events to happen is just delegates being implemented and waiting to be triggered by any relevant events happening on the run loop

the nsoperationqueue was created by me, it is not the main queue

Comment: @Nonnus: This simply reinforces that the only way you'll find out for sure what's slowing your app down is in Instruments.